# Login system with infinite loop error

Tags: python

I'm coding myself a "simple" login system everything works ok up until the `LOGIN` part.

The `while` loop at the end only happens once even though I put another user rather than what I created when I ran the program. I got it to work at some point, but then there was another issue where the `while` loop would happen over and over again.

```
import re
users = {}
status = ""


while status != "r":
    status = input("Press R to register!\n")

    if status == "r":
        createUser = input("Create your Username: ")
        while len(createUser)< 5:                                   #checks user len
            print("Username should contain at least 5 characters!")

            createUser = input("Create your Username: ")            #repeat if user len < 5

        while not re.match("^[a-z]*$" , createUser):                   # denies blank spaces
            print("Cannot use blank spaces")
            createUser = input("Create your Username: ")

        if createUser in users:
            print("Username already used!")
        else:
            createPass = input("Create your Password: ")
            while len(createPass) < 5:                              #checks pass len
                print("Password too short!\n          Password should contain at least 5 characters!\n")
                createPass = input("Create your Password: ")        #repeat if pass len < 5

            while not re.match("^[a-z]*$", createPass):  # denies blank spaces
                print("Cannot use blank spaces")
                createPass = input("Create your Password: ")


            else:
                users[createUser] = createPass  #adds user and pass to users
            print("User created!")

        #LOGIN
            for createUser in users:
                username = input("Username: ")
                if username == createUser in users:
                    password = input("Password: ")
                else:
                    while username != createUser:
                        print("User unregistered! Please register!")
                        createUser = input("Create your Username:")
```

Comment: What is `if username == createUser in users:` supposed to do

Comment: P.S.: I`m a noob , criticise everything you see I`ve done wrong , I really want to learn more python . Thank you!

Comment: I was hopin it would check if the username written is the same as the one created earlier , and if it is proceed to the password input..

Comment: Try adding the .lower to your variable in the input variable, `status = input("Enter 'R' to register: ").lower()`.

Comment: Couple of things: the "adds user and pass to users" line doesn't need to be in an `else` statement. Why is the "LOGIN" section inside your main registration loop? I mean, the loop to register should be ok, but after that you want each user to sort of "login"?

Comment: Yeah , I do want eveyone to "login" ,   I mean this code won`t be used anywhere ... I just want to see if could do it :d.. Also , I`ve changed the indentation for the login section , now it is all underneath while status != "r"(the very first bit) I think it belongs there?... But I still have the same issue with my login section :|

Comment: any other ideas , please???

Comment: Try to break your code down into functions. You should very rarely need to use three levels of indenting.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def login():
    username = input("Username: ")

    if username not in users:
        print("User unregistered! Please register!")
        register()
        return

    password = input("Password: ")

    if users[username] != password
        print("Password invalid")
```

I've rewritten your code here. Notice how I've broken it down into functions which do one thing:

- usernameValidator
- passwordValidator
- getUsername
- getPassword
- register
- login

Beginning of the program:

```
import re
users = {}
```

Now we define some validators to check if the username/password are correct:

```
def usernameValidator(username):
    errorMessage = ""
    if len(username) < 5:
        errorMessage += "Username should contain at least 5 characters!\n"
    if not re.match("^[a-z]*$" , username):       # Note... this checks for more than just blank spaces!
        errorMessage += "Cannot use blank spaces\n"
    if username in users:
        errorMessage += "Username already used!\n"
    return errorMessage

def passwordValidator(password):
    errorMessage = ""
    if len(password) < 5:
        errorMessage += "Password should contain at least 5 characters!\n"
    if not re.match("^[a-z]*$" , password):       # Note... this checks for more than just blank spaces!
        errorMessage += "Cannot use blank spaces\n"
    return errorMessage
```

Now we write the getUsername/getPassword functions which talk with the user:

```
def getUsername():
    username = input("Create your Username: ")
    errorMsg = usernameValidator(username)
    print(errorMsg)

    return username if errorMsg == "" else ""

def getPassword():
    password = input("Create your Password: ")
    errorMsg = passwordValidator(password)
    print(errorMsg)

    return password if errorMsg == "" else ""
```

Putting it all together, we write register/login:

```
def register():
    username = ""
    password = ""

    while username == "":
        username = getUsername()

    while password == "":
        password = getPassword()

    users[username] = password
    print("User created!")

def login():
    username = input("Username: ")

    if username not in users:
        print("User unregistered! Please register!")
        register()
        return

    password = input("Password: ")

    if users[username] != password:
        print("Password invalid")
```

Finally, we may run:

```
while True:
    status = input("Press R to register!\nPress L to login\n")

    if status.lower() == "r":
        register()
    if status.lower() == "l":
        login()
```

[Try it online](https://repl.it/DsrJ).

Answer (score 1):

First, `"^[a-z]*$"` tests for no lowercase letters, it does not mean "no blank spaces", so I have corrected that for you with `"\\s+"`

You really need to learn about methods and break your problem down.

1) Ask for the username

```
def get_username():
    while True:
        uname = input("Create your Username: ")
        if len(uname) < 5:
            print("Username should contain at least 5 characters!")
            continue
        if re.search("\\s+", uname):
            print("Cannot use blank spaces")
            continue
        break # input successful
    return uname
```

2) Ask for the password

```
def get_password():
    while True:
        passwd = input("Create your Password: ")
        if len(passwd) < 5:
            print("Password too short!\n\tPassword should contain at least 5 characters!\n")
            continue
        if re.search("\\s+", passwd):
            print("Cannot use blank spaces")
            continue
        break # input successful
    return passwd
```

3) Register

```
def register():
    while True:
        uname = get_username()
        if uname not in users:
            break  # continue to get password
        else:
            print("Username already used!")

    passwd = get_password()
    if passwd:
        users[uname] = passwd
    print("User created!")
```

4) Attempt login (3 max attempts). It is currently unclear how you want to run this...

```
def login():
    for i in range(3):
        username = input("Username: ")
        if username in users:
            password = input("Password: ")
            if users[username] != password:
                print("Wrong username or password")
        else:
            print("User does not exist")
    else:
        print("Max attempts reached")
```

5) (optional) Learn about [D.R.Y](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) since your tests are essentially the same

```
def test_input(s):
    if len(s) < 5:
        print("Input should contain at least 5 characters!")
        return False
    if re.search("\\s+", s):
        print("Cannot use blank spaces")
        return False
    return True
```

6) Run some code that uses all these methods.

```
status = input("Press R to register!\n")
if status.lower() == "r":
    register()
```

Comment: Haha, we posted an answer at the same time ;)

Comment: @MateenUlhaq I noticed :)